# SQL Query Distinct two columns, Max(date) and retrieve ID

Tags: sql-server, max, distinct

I'm having trouble figuring out how to make this query work. I've tried everything under the sun to avoid looping.

The table has `ID` (pk), `UserID`, `BookID`, `BookDate` (datetime), and `SellerID`. There are duplicate combinatins of `UserID` and `BookID`.

I am trying to retrieve distinct records by `UserID` and `BookID` that have the most recent `BookDate`. That's easy enough (below), but I also need to retrieve the `ID` and `SellerID` columns for the returned record. That's where I'm having trouble...

```
Select Distinct 
    UserID, CourseID, MAX(AssignedON) 
From 
    AssignmentS 
Group By 
    UserID, CourseID
```

Every time I add a join I get all records. I've tried rowover, exists and nothing seems to work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
select userid,courseid,bookdate,sellerid from
 (select userid,courseid,bookdate,sellerid,
         row_number() over (partition by userid,courseid 
                            order by bookdate desc) as RNUM
   from yourtable where yourwhere)
  where rnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for posting.  It's telling me I have errors...  every field in the very first select are "invalid columns".  They are in the table, spelled correctly, etc.

Comment: You probably need to alias the inner select and change the select to use the alias for those colums

Answer (score 0):

[This][1]

[1]: http://coding.feron.it/2012/08/mssql-having-maxid-id-problem-row_number-partition/ blog post describes in detail how to do this with multiple tables

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  I just had to move things around a bit and this is working perfectly!

select userid,courseid,bookdate,sellerid from (
 select * row_number() over(partition by userid,courseid,                          order by bookdate desc) as RNUM
   from yourtable where yourwhere)
  where rnum = 1;